# How to (de)serialize an EnumMap using Jackson and default typing?

Tags: java, javascript, dictionary, enums, jackson

I have an object in which one of the properties is a `Map<MyEnum, Object>`.

As my application is quite big, I've enabled default typing as so :

```
    ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
        .configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

This is rather good, generally speaking.

But, as Javascript doesn't support object keys when using objects as hashes, when I put some data in that map from the javascript side, the object is transformed into a string.

As a consequence, the JSON I receive contains

```
     "MyClass": {
        "contextElements": {
          "userCredentials": {
            "UserCredentials": {
              "login": "admin",
              "password": "admin",
              }
            }
          }
        },
```

When deserializing that, Jackson fails with the following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid type id 'userCredentials' (for id type 'Id.class'): no such class found
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.ClassNameIdResolver.typeFromId(ClassNameIdResolver.java:72)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.TypeDeserializerBase._findDeserializer(TypeDeserializerBase.java:61)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer._deserialize(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:87)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsWrapperTypeDeserializer.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:221)
```

Which I quite well understand : Jackson doesn't understand the `Map<MyEnum, Object>` declaration in my class and, although `MyEnum` is a final class, wants some type metadata added (hey, maybe it's a bug ?!).

What can I do to ahve that code working ?

I'm using Jackson 1.5.2

Comment: It may not matter here, but you really should upgrade to a later Jackson version. If you want to stay with 1.x, 1.9(.13) is the latest -- many bugs have been fixed since 1.5.

Comment: @StaxMan well, I've thought about that, but don't have yet met any real Jackson bug. But I may change my mind ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so, the question states it correctly : it is not possible to use JSON maps in which keys are not strings. As a consequence, to emulate the Java Map in javascript, one has to go a longer path, which would typically involve transforming the map into ... something else.

What I chose was the quite usual array of arrays :

a map such as

```
{
    a:b,
    c:d,
}
```

Will then be translated into the array

```
[
    [a,b],
    [c,d],
]
```

What are the detailled steps required to obtain that result

## Configure custom (de)serialization

This is obtained by setting a serialization factory into the object mapper, as [Jackson doc clearly explains](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers) :

```
/**
 * Associates all maps with our custom serialization mechanism, which will transform them into arrays of arrays
 * @see MapAsArraySerializer
 * @return
 */
@Produces
public SerializerFactory createSerializerFactory() {
    CustomSerializerFactory customized = new CustomSerializerFactory();
    customized.addGenericMapping(Map.class, new MapAsArraySerializer());
    return customized;
}

public @Produces ObjectMapper createMapper() {
    ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    // ....
    // now configure serializer
    jsonMapper.setSerializerFactory(createSerializerFactory());
    // ....
    return jsonMapper;
}
```

The process seems quite simple, mainly because serialization provides quite correct polymorphism features in serialization, which are not that good for deserialization. Indeed, as [doc also states](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomDeserializers), deserialization requires adding explicit class mappings, which are not used in any object-oriented fashion (inheritence is **not** supported there)

```
/**
 * Defines a deserializer for each and any used map class, as there is no inheritence support ind eserialization
 * @return
 */
@Produces
public DeserializerProvider createDeserializationProvider() {
    // Yeah it's not even a standard Jackson class, it'll be explained why later
    CustomDeserializerFactory factory = new MapAsArrayDeserializerFactory();
    List<Class<? extends Map>> classesToHandle = new LinkedList<>();
    classesToHandle.add(HashMap.class);
    classesToHandle.add(LinkedHashMap.class);
    classesToHandle.add(TreeMap.class);
    for(Class<? extends Map> c : classesToHandle) {
        addClassMappingFor(c, c, factory);
    }
    // and don't forget interfaces !
    addClassMappingFor(Map.class, HashMap.class, factory);
    addClassMappingFor(SortedMap.class, TreeMap.class, factory);
    return new StdDeserializerProvider(factory);
}

private void addClassMappingFor(final Class<? extends Map> detected, final Class<? extends Map> created, CustomDeserializerFactory factory) {
    factory.addSpecificMapping(detected, new MapAsArrayDeserializer() {

        @Override
        protected Map createNewMap() throws Exception {
            return created.newInstance();
        }
    });
}

// It's the same createMapper() method that was described upper
public @Produces ObjectMapper createMapper() {
    ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    // ....
    // and deserializer
    jsonMapper.setDeserializerProvider(createDeserializationProvider());
    return jsonMapper;
}
```

Now we have correctly defined how (de)serialization is customized, or do we have ? In fact, no : the `MapAsArrayDeserializerFactory` deserves its own explanation.

After some debugging, I found that `DeserializerProvider` delegates to the `DeserializerFactory` when no deserializer exists for class, which is cool. But, the `DeserializerFactory` creates the deserializer according to the "kind" of obejct : if it is a collection, then a CollectionDeserializer will be used (to read the array into a Collection). If it's a Map, then the MapDeserializer will be used.

Unfortunatly, this resolution uses the java class given in the JSON stream (especially when using [polymorphic deserialization](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonPolymorphicDeserialization), which was my case). As a consequence, configuring custom deserialization has no effect, unless the `CustomDeserializerFactory` is customized ... like that :

```
public class MapAsArrayDeserializerFactory extends CustomDeserializerFactory {
    @Override
    public JsonDeserializer<?> createMapDeserializer(DeserializationConfig config, MapType type, DeserializerProvider p) throws JsonMappingException {
        return createBeanDeserializer(config, type, p);
    }
}
```

Yup, i deserialize all maps as beans. But now, all my deserializers are correctly called.

## Serializing

Now, serialization is a rather simple task :

```
public class MapAsArraySerializer extends JsonSerializer<Map> {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private Set asListOfLists(Map<?, ?> value) {
        Set returned = new HashSet<>();
        for(Map.Entry e : value.entrySet()) {
            returned.add(Arrays.asList(e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
        }
        return returned;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Map value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Collection entries = asListOfLists(value);
        jgen.writeObjectField("entries", entries);
    }

    @Override
    public void serializeWithType(Map value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider, TypeSerializer typeSer) throws IOException,
                    JsonProcessingException {
        Collection entries = asListOfLists(value);
        typeSer.writeTypePrefixForObject(value, jgen);
        jgen.writeObjectField("entries", entries);
        typeSer.writeTypeSuffixForObject(value, jgen);
    }
}
```

## Deserialization

And deserialization is not more complex :

```
public abstract class MapAsArrayDeserializer<Type extends Map> extends JsonDeserializer<Type> {

    protected Type newMap(Collection c, Type returned) {
        for(Object o : c) {
            if (o instanceof List) {
                List l = (List) o;
                if(l.size()==2) {
                    Iterator i = l.iterator();
                    returned.put(i.next(), i.next());
                }
            }
        }
        return returned;
    }

    protected abstract Type createNewMap() throws Exception;

    @Override
    public Type deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        if(jp.getCurrentToken().equals(JsonToken.START_OBJECT)) {
            JsonToken nameToken = jp.nextToken();
            String name = jp.getCurrentName();
            if(name.equals("entries")) {
                jp.nextToken();
                Collection entries = jp.readValueAs(Collection.class);
                JsonToken endMap = jp.nextToken();
                try {
                    return newMap(entries, createNewMap());
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    throw new IOException("unable to create receiver map", e);
                }
            } else {
                throw new IOException("expected \"entries\", but field name was \""+name+"\"");
            }
        } else {
            throw new IOException("not startying an object ? Not possible");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Type deserializeWithType(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt, TypeDeserializer typeDeserializer) throws IOException,
                    JsonProcessingException {
        Object value = typeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(jp, ctxt);
        return (Type) value;
    }
}
```

Well, expected the class is left abstract t have each declared subtype create the right map instance.

## And now

And now it works seamlessly on Java side (cause the Javascript has to have a map-equivalent object to read those datas.